# Add new options to dropdownlist in runtime using jquery plugin selectbox.js

Tags: jquery, css

This is my control,

```
<select name="ddlRequestType" id="ddlRequestType">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
```

I want to add new options to dropdown from database using ajax webmethod.
but i am getting to add.

this is my ajax web method code.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#ddlRequestType").selectbox();
            loadFilterData();
        });
        function loadFilterData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Index.aspx/loadFilterData",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    //debugger;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        }
                },
                error: function () {
 }     

         });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: can you share link for selectbox.js that you are using?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "i am getting to add".  Please describe the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

just create items

```
var ul = $(document.getElementById("ddlRequestType"));
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    var li = $(document.createElement("li")).val(data.d[i].value).text(data.d[i].text);
    ul.append(li);
}
```